# sublime text remove repository

Tags: python, repository, sublimetext2

I have installed package control, and I use it frequently, the problem is that I added a new repository and it is wrong, and when I try to install other package, sublime throw exception, somebody know how can I remove a repository in sublime text.

Note: I have the problem in a OSX.

Comment: what is the error?  share it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on `Sublime Text 2` on the menu bar, then `Preferences -> Browse Packages` to open up a Finder window pointing to `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`. Open the `User` folder and open `Package Control.sublime-settings` in Sublime Text. You should see a list of installed packages, and a key (possible down at the bottom) called `"repositories"`. The file should look something like this:

```json
{
    "auto_upgrade_last_run": null,
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "PackageName",
        "AnotherPackageName",
        "AwesomeSublimePlugin",
        "Neon Color Scheme"
    ],
    "repositories":
    [
        "https://github.com/SoMeUsEr/BadURL"
    ]
}
```

and to delete the repository you should make it look like this:

```
{
    "auto_upgrade_last_run": null,
    "installed_packages":
    [
        "PackageName",
        "AnotherPackageName",
        "AwesomeSublimePlugin",
        "Neon Color Scheme"
    ]
}
```

Make sure you delete the comma `,` after the closing square bracket `]` and before the closing curly brace `}` or Sublime will complain at you.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the Package Control settings from the Menu bar under:
Preferences -> Package Settings -> Package Control -> Settings - User.

From there you can edit or remove the bad URL.